# How to re-use vector with set elements?

Tags: c++, linux, windows, vector, raspberry-pi

So I'm streaming my Rasperry Pi camera to my computer using my program but. The vector listed below is giving me problems. It gives me `std::bad_alloc` after about 30 seconds of streaming. Is there any way to reuse this vector over and over again in a loop (e.g resize, clear)?
Here is the simplified code:

```
while(isRunning)
{
    recv(Connection, received_message, sizeof(received_message), NULL); //receiving the size of image in bytes
    fileSize = atoi(received_message);

    std::vector<char> fileData(fileSize); //<- this vector is giving me problems

    recv(Connection, &fileData[0], CHUNK_SIZE, 0); //Receiving the image

    //The code loops over and over again
}
```

Comment: this code doesn't make sense. you can't pass a pointer to a vector to recv function.  It should be crashing faster than after 30s.

Comment: @MK., the OP is passing a pointer to a vector element (so, a `char*`), not to the whole vector.

Comment: ALso note there is nothing to prevent `recv(Connection, received_message, sizeof(received_message), NULL);` from returning only part of `received_message` resulting in a totally screwed up `fileSize`.

Comment: @SingerOfTheFall uh... this might work, but I'm pretty sure you are not supposed to be making guesses like that about internals of vector

Comment: @MK. It's not much of a guess. `std::vector<char>` is guaranteed to contain a contiguous array of `char`. The safe thing to do is use `std::vector::data`, though.

Comment: Check the result of that `atoi`, most probably you are passing a very large (or negative) value to the vector constructor.

Comment: you should also not be blindly trusting that fileSize you just read from the network.  If it is huge, you will fail to allocate.

Comment: why is std::vector<char> guaranteed to contain a continuous array of char?

Comment: @user4581301: it must be noted that the only case where `data()` is safer is when the array is empty (where it's still guaranteed to return some valid pointer, unlike `operator[]`); in all other cases they are guaranteed to be exactly the same.

Comment: @MK.: because the standard says so; also, because otherwise it would break many useful use cases (interoperability with C and access to elements through raw pointers in first place).

Comment: @MatteoItalia I suspected that, but wasn't certain. Currently reading the standard to dig up the piece on it for MK.

Comment: Great Discussion guys. Is there any function I should be performing in the end of the loop for the vector? Such as fileData.clear()? Or it wouldn't really matter?

Comment: OK, [vector.overview] states "A vector satisfies all of the requirements  ... for an element type other than bool, of a contiguous container" This sets off a chain of contiguous containers supporting contiguous iterators which [iterator.requirements.general] requires "that, for integral values n and dereferenceable iterator values a and (a + n), *(a + n) is equivalent to *(addressof(*a) + n)"

Comment: Man I will never learn to love this language.

Comment: Kevin, the first thing to do is be absolutely certain `fileSize` is not insane. There is nothing in the presented code that ensures you are getting all the data you ask for in a given call to `recv`. It is really easy for `recv(Connection, &fileData[0], CHUNK_SIZE, 0);` to return after 1 byte because it's the only byte available, leaving the next `recv(Connection, received_message, sizeof(received_message), NULL);` to read part of the current image as `received_message` and interpret it not as image data, but as the size of the next image and try to allocate, say, a terabyte of RAM.

Comment: @MK  so after 5 minutes of streaming, it crashed. Luckily it hit a break point. fileSize= 4294967292 .

Comment: Instead of creating the vector over and over again, declare the vector before the while loop, and simply call `resize()` on that vector.  The `resize()` is smart in that it will only need to call the allocator if the requested size is greater than the capacity.

Comment: @user4581301 Yes it was probably the file size that was screwing it up. How did it get so big though?

Comment: @paulMcKenzie Do I call anything before resize is called? (e.g clear)

Comment: @KevinDuarte No, there is no need for `clear()`.  I updated my comment to point out that `resize()` is smart.  The vector has a "capacity", which can be different than the `size()`.  You can have a vector that has a current size() of `0`, but have a max capacity of 1000, meaning there is no need reallocate as long as the number of entries is less than 1000.

Comment: @KevinDuarte -- Also, you're making the mistake of not checking the return values of the functions you're calling.   If there is an error, your loop continues as if there is nothing wrong.  Basically when you are calling a third-party or any API function that returns a value back to you, take heed in what that return value may denote -- don't just ignore it.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie My entries is atleast 100k bytes of image data every second, so should i have to reallocate?

Comment: What Paul McKenzie is suggesting is an optimization, a good one, but it won't help in reading the data correctly. Focus on getting a working program, then tune it. What this tweak will do is reuse the same storage until a larger image arrives, reallocate for that larger image, and then use the new storage until an even bigger image arrives. The current version will get a new allocation every time needed or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TCP is a streaming protocol. It has no concept of messages. Writing 10,000 bytes in at one end of the connection does not mean all 10,000 bytes will arrive at the receiver and be available all at once.

As a result, `recv` works with what is has. It returns whatever is currently available, and if nothing is available `recv` waits until data becomes available. This means if you ask for 10,000 bytes you may get anywhere between 1 byte and 10,000 bytes entirely at the whim of the network stack, the maximum amount of data that can go in one IP packet, and too many other variables to list.

So

```
recv(Connection, received_message, sizeof(received_message), NULL);
```

may return before it receives all of `received_message`. `fileSize` will computed from bad input, most likely a string that isn't null terminated and runs off the end of the buffer triggering undefined behaviour, and garbage in gives garbage out.

This incorrect `fileSize` is then used to size a `vector` which will now almost certainly be the wrong size. If it is too small,

```
recv(Connection, &fileData[0], CHUNK_SIZE, 0);
```

may run off the end of the `vector`for more undefined behaviour. If it is too large, the system may not be able to allocate storage for the `vector` because there isn't enough contiguous storage available. This appears to be what has happened to OP.

Solution: Loop all calls to `recv` until the required amount of data has arrived before proceeding. Write in an alternate path to handle closed or failed connections. All calls must read the correct amount of data or

```
recv(Connection, &fileData[0], CHUNK_SIZE, 0);
```

could exit early leaving the next

```
recv(Connection, received_message, sizeof(received_message), NULL);
```

to read part of the image as `received_message`, resulting in a `fileSize` every bit as insane as if `received_message` was not completely filled.

Also Consider setting a timeout on `recv` so that you have a chance to read an exit flag should you wish to terminate the program. Otherwise it may block forever for data that will never arrive.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily reuse your `std::vector` like this:

```
std::vector<char> fileData;

while(isRunning)
{
    ssize_t n = recv(Connection, received_message, sizeof(received_message), 0); //receiving the size of image in bytes
    if (n < 0)
        throw std::runtime_error(std::string("Connection error (getting fileSize)") + strerror(errno));
    assert(n == sizeof(received_message));

    fileSize = atoi(received_message);

    if (fileSize > maxFileSize or fileSize == 0)
        throw std::runtime_error("Invalid fileSize " + std::to_string(fileSize));

    fileData.resize(fileSize);

    size_t received = 0;
    while (received < fileSize)
    {
        ssize_t n = recv(Connection, fileData.data() + received, fileSize - received, 0); //Receiving the image
        if (n < 0)
            throw std::runtime_error(std::string("Connection error (getting image)") + strerror(errno));
        received += n;
    }
    //The code loops over and over again
}
```

A few notes:

- Handle the event that the first `recv` does not receive `sizeof(received_message)` bytes (currently protected by the `assert`)
- You should define `maxFileSize`
- Include the `<cassert>`, `<exception>` and `<string>` headers
- Compile using `-std=c++11`

Comment: Asserting on a perfectly normal state, `recv` not returning the requested amount of data, is a very, very bad idea.

Comment: @user4581301 Yes, this is left as an exercise to OP (an example is present though)